# Global OS X framework clashes with local one and prevents Canopy from opening

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, enthought, canopy

In my system (Mac OS X 10.6.8) it is impossible to open Enthought Canopy, since it crashes immediately with many of those errors in the Console:

> 11/05/14 20.28.00 [0x0-0x1271270].com.Canopy[53010]   objc[53015]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /Users/name/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/../../../../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui and /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

followed by

> 11/05/14 20.28.00 [0x0-0x1271270].com.Canopy[53010]   QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x102837760) is not the object's thread (0x120281040).
>
> 11/05/14 20.28.00 [0x0-0x1271270].com.Canopy[53010]   Cannot move to target thread (0x102837760)
>
> 11/05/14 20.28.00 [0x0-0x1271270].com.Canopy[53010]   On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.

In fact I have a version of Qt installed in the default location (so I have many frameworks of the type `/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework` ) and this appears to conflict with the version that Canopy has inside. Is there a way to resolve this conflict without removing the  preexisting Qt installation?

Ironically  I decided to install Canopy to circumvent the problems that I had when installing **chaco**, the only program that I needed, because it required Qt and pyside. This has triggered a long yak shaving marathon of installing one program after the other (Qt->pyQt->ets->vtk->mayavi->chaco->pyside->...) that I hoped to escape by installing Canopy. Therefore, I am pretty desperate at that point.

Comment: Whoever packaged/built Canopy needs to get their act together and properly refer to the bundled framework.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the age of your OS you're probably running an older version of Canopy also.
I downloaded the current (64-bit) version from their website and ran the following script against it:

```
#!/bin/tcsh #-x

# create a working directory
if (! -e ~/Canopy ) then
    mkdir ~/Canopy
endif

# get a list of all files (and their types)
if (! -e ~/Canopy/Canopy-files.txt ) then
    find /Volumes/Enthought/Canopy.app/ -type f -exec file {} \; > ~/Canopy/Canopy-files.txt
endif

# grep that list for all dylibs
if (! -e ~/Canopy/Canopy-dylibs.txt ) then
    grep 'dynamically linked shared library' ~/Canopy/Canopy-files.txt > ~/Canopy/Canopy-dylibs.txt
endif

# `otool -DL` all dylibs in that list looking for 'QtGui'
foreach line ( "`cat ~/Canopy/Canopy-dylibs.txt`" )
    set file = `echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1]}'`
    otool -DL $file | grep 'QtGui'
end
```

All reported QtGui paths were:

```
    @rpath/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.5)
```

and the actual dylib was at:

```
/Volumes/Enthought/Canopy.app//appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui:
```

To check your app change the path on line 10 to the path of your version of the application.

If you find invalid paths you may be able to change then via the 'install_name_tool'. Warning: this tool fails silently; always check to see if it did what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this would be if your PYTHONPATH environment variable were set to point into another Python installation. This is an incorrect use of PYTHONPATH, which is intended to point to modules and packages (typically in-house) which have not been installed into Python. It is not intended to point into the guts of any Python installation (not even the one that is running, and certainly not into a different one). Enthought is considering ways to make Canopy more robust against this type of error. Meanwhile, you would need to unset PYTHONPATH before starting Canopy.

If this is not the case, please report the value of all your environment variables (redacted as necessary). You can get this by typing the `env` command in Terminal.